# Is it ok to use "many" instead of "much" in context like this?

Tags: determiners, exam-questions

There is a question in my text book.

> I haven't read ___ on the newly developed detection device so far but
>   it seems like a good read.
>
> (A) many of the reports
>
> (B) much of the report
>
> (C) much report
>
> (D) many reports

The answer was (B). Is it OK, if I use "many of the report"?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/grammar/a_lot_much_many.html It explains the difference between much, many, and a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It doesn't sound right. Generally, *'many'* is used when a reference to something that is **countable** is taken, whereas *'much'* can be used for uncountable things. I'll give you an example :

> The article didn't cover **much** about the current state of the city.

It is wrong if the sentence had been phrased as:

> The article didn't cover **many** about the current state of the city.

*'Article'* and *'City'* are countable terms. But, the primary focus is on the content of the article. Similarly,

> I haven't read much of the report on the newly developed detection device so far but it seems like a good read.

means that the subject has seen or heard about the report, the one report, that talks about the "newly developed detection device", but didn't read the entire report. It may sound confusing, but let me change the sentence into a slightly different version, without changing the meaning :

> I have read very little of the report on the newly developed detection device so far but it seems like a good read.

[This might help you : Much vs Many](http://grammarist.com/usage/many-much/)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. But you can say "many of the **reports**" in plural form like the answer (A).

In case you don't know the difference between **much** and **many** in your example, the first is used for the countable things and the latter is for the uncountable.

The difference between the two answers is the following:

If you choose:

> I haven't read **many of the reports** on the newly developed detection device so far but it seems like a good read.

You are saying that there is a number of different reports on that topic and you have read only few of them.

But in case of:

> I haven't read **much of the report** on the newly developed detection device so far but it seems like a good read.

You are saying there is only one report on the topic and you haven't read a lot of it. You only read a small part.

So I think both answer (A) and (B) are correct, but saying "**many of the report**" doesn't make sense because a single report is uncountable.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! According to the text book (A) is wrong because the subject of the later part is `it`, so the noun must be singular. But I think this sentence is ambiguous, this `it` can represent "a action of reading" and "the report" both, isn't it?

Comment: I agree.Good point. It is ambiguous.